# How to use COUNTIF and COUNTA together in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a single column and I want to count how many rows do NOT contain "www." but at the same time are not blank. I have tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E79,"<>*www.*",E2:E79,"?*")
```

This seems to work, but only for text. It will not count columns if it has numbers. I have also tried:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(E2:E79,"<>*www.*"),COUNTA(E2:E79))
```

This just returns TRUE. Can someone please show me the correct formula I need to use?

Answer (score 3):

A universal COUNTIF formula for counting **all non-blank cells** in a specified range:

```
=COUNTIF(range,"<>"&"")
```

This formula works correctly with all value types - text, dates and numbers.

So you might want to use

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E79,"<>*www.*",E2:E79,"<>"&"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E79,"<>*www.*",E2:E79,"<>")
```